# How would one paint a narrow circle around the edge of a circular object in blender

Tags: vertex-paint

I need to paint a circular border onto an object in Blender 2.83. After playing with the vertex paint, I have not been able to figure this out. This should be simple, but so far have not had much success.

Comment: Could you explain a little more what you mean by a circular border?

Comment: Consider to mark any answer as accepted (you can change it any time), so others can see it  from main list and system is not pocking Q seqeuntly on top. https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour Thank you to keep site organnized.

Answer (score 4):

*In general, it doesnt sound as useful to draw narrow circle in Vertex Paint. For such result you would need a lot of vertices or very specific vertices for this purpose. It would be better if you can closer describe what is your goal. Maybe you dont need to use a Vertex Paint for it.*

---

Narrow circle you can achive by many ways ...

### version 01 **Material**

- create specific geometry and assign one material to object and create another one assigned to specific faces.

[image]

### version 02 **Texture**

- create material with Image texture

### version 03 **Vertex Paint**

- I dont know if there is a specific tool for it (Sculpt mode had some paint from curve). One way that lays on vertices position as well - you can create a Vertex Group by assigning vertices to a group ... (here displayed in Weight Paint mode)

[image]

... switch to *Vertex Paint* mode and use **Vertex Color from Weight** operator.

[image]

### version 04 **Paint Editor**

- in *Image* editor in 2.91 go to side panel (N) *Tool - Stroke - Stroke Method - Curve*, add a new and with Ctrl manually create a circle shape from curve, than press *Draw*

[image: Paint Editor]

Comment: Thanks for the input. I finally abandoned the paint functions and created additional loops to define the width of the circular border and then assigned the material. It worked, but being new to Blender it seemed that the paint function made more sense, but gave up on it. Really didn't know how to work on a created circular shape in that program, but played with it for a good while with no success.

Comment: No problem :) Great if it helped.

Answer (score 2):

Just another option to add to  @vklidu's list: if you toggle from Vertex Paint to Edit mode, you can make a face or vertex selection to use as a mask for painting.(The header icons bottom-center in the Paint-Mode pictures)

[image]

A face-mask masks face-corner vertices, including only the face-corners which  belong to faces in the selection.

[image]

A vertex-mask includes all face-corners under the selected vertices:

[image]

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> quickly fills the masked area with the active color, although I can't for the life of me find that shortcut in any of the menus.

[image]

The gif shows:

- Switching into Face-Mask mode in Vertex Paint
- Tabbing into Edit Mode from Vertex Paint
- Making a selection of faces
- Tabbing back into Vertex Paint, and hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> to fill... ( this could have been painting, if you preferred)
- Switching back out of Face-Mask mode

Comment: Hi @vklidu.. see edit.. does that help?

Comment: Here are a couple images.